# React/Rails/Devise - Devise timeoutable not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to logout a user after certain minutes of inactivity.
So far I have this on my `User` model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :validatable, :timeoutable
```

And on my `devise.rb` which is inside `config/initializers`

```
    config.timeout_in = 5.minutes
```

However after 5 minutes of inactivity, the user is still being logged in. Going through devise and several stackoverflow questions, unfortunately didn't help me. Did I miss something here? Adding columns for timeoutable?

Comment: The user is logged in even after refreshing the page?

Comment: Yes. The user is never logged out. I waited more than five minutes.